# Change zoom magnifier product image size in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, zooming

I'm struggling for a very long time to get the magnified or lightbox image set to a different (custom) size instead of the full size uploaded image.

I found out that it is controlled by this line of code in wc-template-functions .php on line 1399:

```
$full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'full' ) );
```

I tried to create a function to change 'full' to "preview' or 'large' but I can't get my code to work. See my code below:

```
function change_magnifier_lightbox_image_size(){
  echo "De post" , $post;

  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
  echo "De ID ", $post_thumbnail_id;
  $filemeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_thumbnail_id, FALSE );
  echo "De filemeta ", $filemeta;

    if ($filemeta['width']>3071 || $filemeta['height']>3071){
      $full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'preview' ) );
    }else{
      $full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'large' ) );
    };
};
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'change_magnifier_lightbox_image_size' );
```

$post is set to global.

I don't get any echo at all, also not from the strings and the code is in my child themes functions.php. What am I missing?

Comment: thanks. I changed 99 into '99' because of an error but it is still not working. Same behavior as before. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some errors and mistakes in your code. Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', 'change_magnifier_lightbox_image_size', 20, 1 );
function change_magnifier_lightbox_image_size( $size ){
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() );
    $attachment   = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $thumbnail_id, FALSE );

    // Always return a value in a filter hook
    return ( $attachment['width'] > 3071 || $attachment['height'] > 3071 ) ? 'preview' : 'large';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to unhook the default WooCommerce action

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20);
```

and then you put your code.

Comment: thank you for your reply but your suggestion removes the images from my single product page entirely. I want the image shown but when hovering it (magnifiying) or clicking the zoom button a custom image instead of the full size.

Answer (score 0):

It should be  `add_filter` not apply_filters

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'change_magnifier_lightbox_image_size' );
```

and you must return value in filters, check `add_filter()`  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Comment: thanks but it is not working. The top of the page loads but then after the loading indicator spinning for about 30 seconds the rest of the page remains white. Any suggestions?

Comment: Further investigation tells me that the following error is thrown: :  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ..... Is it in a loop somehow oris it something else.

Comment: because you are adding apply_filters('woocommerce_gallery_full_size') inside the function, the function will call itself infinitly.

Comment: Oempf,..... that's a difficult one. Would you be so kind to edit your answer with te original line from wc-template-functions .php, line 1399 in mind. I'm really stuck here. What ever I try it fails. Bottom line: please tell me what I have to do.